# Listing Everything in an ArrayList

Tags: java

OK, so I have a project that involves organizing books in a Library. My issue is that I have to create a method called listAuthors(). This method should return a list of the book's authors. It does not seem too difficult, but I am just unsure how to do this, if someone could perhaps show me a way to achieve this or at least point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Book {


ArrayList<Author> authors;
private int yearPublished;
private Status status;
private String title, isbn, publisherName;

public Status getStatus() {
    return this.status;
}//end getStatus

public Book() {
    ArrayList<Author> authors = new ArrayList<Author>();
    title = null;
    isbn = null;
    yearPublished = 0;
    publisherName = null;
    status = null;
}//end book constructor

public Book(String title, String publisherName, int yearPublished, Status status, String isbn) {

    this.title = title;
    this.publisherName = publisherName;
    this.yearPublished = yearPublished;
    this.status = status;
    this.isbn = isbn;

}//end book constructor


public void loan() {
    status = status.ONLOAN;
}//end loan


public void inLibrary() {
    status = status.INLIBRARY;
}//end inLibrary


public void lost() {
     status = status.LOST;
}//end lost


public void addAuthor(Author a) {
    authors.add(a);

}//end addAuthor


public String listAuthors() {
    THIS IS WHERE I AM CONFUSED!
}//end listAuthors


public String printReferences() {

}//end printReferences


}//end class
```

So essentially how this will work is that there will be books that users can input. But how would I create this listAuthors method that should return a list of all of the authors in the ArrayList? I was think a while loop or something like that but am unsure. Thanks for the help and if you need any more details just let me know. I appreciate it :)

Comment: [An open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: what exactly you are trying to do? Print the contents of that `ArrayList`?

Comment: Currently, `listAuthors` returns a `String` type, not any sort of `list`. Are you looking to print the contents of the ArrayList?

Comment: *"But how would I create this listAuthors method that should return a list of all of the authors in the ArrayList?"* - Assuming you already have a list of books, then yes, a you will need to iterate/loop of this list and extract the author names and add them to a new `ArrayList` - I highly recommend that you have a go and see what you discover

Comment: this method has to return a String type, which would be the author's names. the ArrayList is intentionally left blank because the users will enter them into the arraylist itself.

Comment: As long as `Author` overrides `toString()`, just `return authors.toString()`.

Comment: @shmosel wow.. that's actually what I needed thanks man! Sorry I'm new to java and am trying to teach myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, this answer falls under the 'point you in the right direction' category. In order to put each author in a string, you need to:

1. Create a string
2. Iterate over every author (most easily done using a for loop)
3. --Append each author's name to the string
4. --Append some kind of separator (e.g., ", ") to the string (unless this is the last author)
5. Return the string

(the dashed line items are inside the loop)

Comment: Thanks! this is actually really helpful for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: The answer is fine regarding [answer] (like you said), especially if you have the quality of the question in mind (see [ask]). Have my up-vote.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have overrided Author's `toString()` method, you can simply return `authors.toString()`. This will call Author's `toString()` on each author in your ArrayList and return authors as a readable list.

Here is an example(with Strings):

```
ArrayList<String> authors = new ArrayList<>();
authors.add("Ivan");
authors.add("Pasha");
System.out.println(authors.toString()); //Prints [Ivan, Pasha]
```